# Finding number of solutions for a simple linear equation with constraints (Combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics

I'm learning Combinatorics from courses on the internet and I have a problem:

So let's say I have this equation
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=6
$$
$$
x_i \in \mathbb{Z}, x_i≥0  | 1≤i≤6
$$
I can count the number of possible solutions using this formula
$$
\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}
$$
where n is the number of variables and k is the number that it is equal to in this case it's 6 for both

but what if I have the same equation but with a different constraints:
$$
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=6
$$
$$
x_i \in \mathbb{Z},0≤x_i≤4  | 1≤i≤6
$$
How would I go about adopting the formula from before? is that even possible?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. It appears that all $x_i$ are integers only, but you should make that explicit in your question.

Comment: can't find Z group in symbols, I'm a newbie to this, I'll just mark it Z and change later

Comment: FYI, in MathJax, you can use something like `$x_i \in \mathbb{Z}$`, which is displayed as $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}$. For more info about using MathJax, see [Short and helpful advice on using MathJax on the site ...](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179/602049) and [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/602049).

Comment: I edited it, it's probably not mathematically accurate way to write it, sorry I'm not an academic I'm just learning.

Comment: You shouldn't worry about very much as I think what you wrote is reasonably good. To learn more about the appropriate math syntax to use in various situations, I suggest you read various other questions & answers here. Also, my previous comment provides links to $2$ meta posts regarding how to use MathJax (which is very similar to $\LaTeX$) on this site, that I suggest you at least initially skim through (especially the second link) as there's a lot there, to get a feeling for how to use MathJax in general, and then just use those posts later as mostly reference sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a mistake in your formula for counting the number of solutions: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

If $0\leq x_i \leq 4$, then this is equivalent to counting the number of ways to solve this equation where $x_i \neq 5, x_i \neq 6$.  If $x_j = 5$ for some $1\leq j \leq 6$, then one of the other $i\neq j$ must be $1$.  There are $6$ ways to pick $j$ then $5$ ways to pick $i$ for a total of $30$ ways for $x_i=5$. Additionally, there are $6$ ways to pick $x_j=6$ where the remaining $x_i=0$.  So if there are (as you've already solved) $462$ ways to solve this equation if $0\leq x_i$, then there are $462 - 30 - 6$ ways to solve the equation with the extra constraint of $x_i\leq 4$.

Comment: So, we're basically counting the part we don't want and subtracting that from the total.
like in The Inclusion-Exclusion principle?

Comment: Your first statement is accurate.  Inclusion-Exclusion is to avoid double counting.  We're just taking a simple set difference in this case. But yeah!

Comment: Are you sure about the mistake in my formula? I see you adjusted the answer, shouldn't it be 462-30-6

Comment: Yes thanks!  Yeah, there is a missing "-1". It should be $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$

Comment: let's say one solution is 0+0+0+0+6=6
and another is 6+0+0+0+0=6
will it count them both? how can I avoid it, because honestly that's what I was trying to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "it"?  In this case, we explicitly counted them.  You've shown two of the six ways $x_i=6$ has a solution.

Comment: My bad then, I modeled my problem poorly, I'll rethink it.